# Airflow with docker not finding local python scripts and directories (ModuleNotFoundError)

Tags: python, docker, airflow, python-module

I am using Airflow with the default `docker-compose.yaml` file. I have my own sorce directories which I want to run from `DAGs`. Structure is like so:

```
root_package
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
├── foo1.py
├── dags
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   └── update.py
├── subdir
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   └── foo2.py
└── plugins
```

First thing I have to do is add this root directory as volume in the docker-compose.yaml file. This is already done by default for the `/dags` and `/plugins` directory. I just added the full root as well like so:

```
volumes:
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}:/opt/airflow
```

Secondly, I need to add my python directories to `PYTHONPATH` because I need to import them from inside a `dag` (ex: update.py):

```
from root_package import foo1

with DAG(
    dag_id="id123", schedule_interval=None, start_date=datetime(2023, 4, 21)
) as dag:
    # call foo1 functions from a PythonOperator
    ...
```

Currently I am getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'root_package'` as a webserver error.

How can add PYTHONPATH within docker-compose file so that airflow adds my root directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Put the fool.py into the plugins directory.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Consider taking the [tour].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).